# Dockerfile not working - running command manually works, but same command through run or entrypoint doesn't work

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

My Dockerfile won't run my entrypoint automatically.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base

RUN apt update
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libssl1.1
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libpulse0
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libasound2
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libicu63
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libpcre2-16-0
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libdouble-conversion1
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libglib2.0-0
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install telnet
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install pulseaudio
RUN apt --yes --force-yes install libasound2-dev

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SDKStandalone/SDKStandalone.csproj", "SDKStandalone/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SDKStandalone/SDKStandalone.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SDKStandalone"
RUN dotnet build "SDKStandalone.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SDKStandalone.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

RUN chmod +x /app/SDKContainer/startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/SDKContainer/startup.sh"]
```

What also doesn't work is if I change the last line to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/SDKContainer/mySDK"]
```

My Startup file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

/app/SDKContainer/mySDK &
```

What does work, is if I open bash from the running container, and do either:

```
chmod +x /app/SDKContainer/startup.sh
/app/SDKContainer/startup.sh
```

Or simply

```
/app/SDKContainer/mySDK
```

Both of those work fine, but I need my SDK to run automatically on container start and I do not want to start it manually. I don't know if it matters, but for completeness - I am debugging in Visual Studio 2019, they are running through a Docker compose YML, and I have selected 'do not debug'.

Docker compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myproject.server:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Server/Dockerfile
  sdkstandalone:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sdkstandalone
    container_name: sdk1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SDKStandalone/Dockerfile
  sdkstandalone2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sdkstandalone
    container_name: sdk2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SDKStandalone/Dockerfile
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Docker Compose": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "serviceActions": {
        "sdkstandalone": "StartWithoutDebugging",
        "myproject.server": "StartDebugging",
        "sdkstandalone2": "StartWithoutDebugging"
      },
      "commandVersion": "1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error when you use Dockefile

Comment: There is no error, the container starts up but the SDK doesn't start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in Visual Studio debugging itself. When it runs without debugging it doesn't work, but running the docker-compose directly from my commandline without Visual Studio works absolutely fine. I will mark this is the correct answer since it solved my issue, but upvoted @triplee for good advice and best practices

Answer (score 3):

The container exits when the entry point process terminates. You have ensured that it terminates immediately. Take out the `&` to run the process in the foreground instead; this will keep your Docker image alive until the job finishes. This is a very common Docker FAQ.

Unless your parent image was specifically designed this way, you should probably use `CMD`, not `ENTRYPOINT`.

As a further aside, `apt` can install multiple packages in one go. Your long list of `RUN` commands near the beginning of your `Dockerfile` can be reduced to just two commands, and run significantly quicker.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on combining the installs.

I removed the ampersand but it still does not work using the startup.sh script.

I also tried ending the dockerfile with `CMD ["/app/SDKContainer/mySDK"]` but that also doesn't work. Is there something else that I am missing here?

Comment: Without knowledge about what the SDK does and how you would tell when it's working, I can't say. Usually "SDK" means just a bunch of components, and you would add some code of your own to exercise some particular functionality it provides. Perhaps you can clarify these parts?

Comment: Of course - In my application I have a button which initiates a TCP connection to the SDK. When the SDK is running, I get success, when it is not running, I get connection refused. By typing `/app/SDKContainer/mySDK` into the bash of the container running the SDK, I get success. By attempting to start it through bash from the Dockerfile, or through the Dockerfile indirectly through the .sh file, I get 'connection refused', showing that it's not running. Subsequently starting it manually does work

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but the actual problem was due to VS2019. Thank you so much though

Answer (score 0):

This problem was killing me. After passed some hours looking for some resolution, I found this forum [Debugging docker compose. VS can't attach to containers](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debugging-docker-compose-vs-cant-attach-to-contain/1551330)

In my case, I updated my VS and there's this problem with Docker Compose v2. They're going to release the fix soon.

For now, disable the version 2, restart Docker and VS. It worked for me.

Command to check current version: `docker-compose --version`

Commando to come back to the previous version: `docker-compose disable-v2`

Hope it helps anyone with the similar issue.